# How to run PSTricks in TeXShop

Tags: pstricks, texshop

Why can't I run the following command in my TeXShop?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 

\begin{document} 
\psset{algebraic=true} 
\pspicture(-2,-0.5)(2,2) 
\psline{<->}(-2,0)(2,0) 
\psline{->}(0,-0.5)(0,2) 
\psplot{-1.5}{1}{x*x+x} 
\endpspicture 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compile it with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 5):

In TeXShop, you can choose the TeX and DVI item from the Typeset menu, and then compile your document.  Alternatively, (and a better solution) you can put the following line in your file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
```

as the first line of your document.  (This line can be generated by TeXShop by choosing the Program item from the Macros menu, and choosing `latex` from the list provided by the macro.)