# Beginners Guide to PSTricks for TeXShop users for math functions

Tags: pstricks

I am looking to get help to plot tangent function. I find TikZ insufficient capability on TeXShop.

I am thinking about PSTricks and TeXShop. Is there any useful documentation or tutorial on packages involved to start plotting math trig function plots.

Comment: PSTricks is a set of packages; TeXShop is an editor. As such the two are really independent of each other.  The following question might be of help if you are intending to use PSTricks with TeXShop, though: [How to run PSTricks in TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66051/2693).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`pst-plot`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pst-plot) package- the following example is taken from page 28 of the documentation

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6.5,-4)(6.5,7.5)
    \psaxes[trigLabelBase=2,dx=\psPiH,xunit=\psPi,trigLabels]%
        {->}(0,0)(-1.7,-3.5)(1.77,6.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{algebraic=true}
    \psplot[yMaxValue=6,yMinValue=-3,linewidth=1.6pt,plotpoints=2000,
        linecolor=red]{-4.55}{4.55}{tan(x)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have some issues compiling to pdf file./article.tex:24: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 
                             
l.24 {->}(0,0)(-1.7,-3.5)(1.77,6.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]

Comment: How do you compile it from source .tex code to .pdf on TeXShop.Any settings on TeXShop I use LateX but I cannot see the desired graphics. I am new to PS tricks although I have used tikz for diagrams.

Comment: @mark If you are using PSTricks you need to compile via "LaTeX=>PS=>PDF". PSTricks doesn't work with pdflatex directly.

Comment: or use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

Comment: @mark The question I linked to in my comment to your question shows you how to run the code in TeXShop.

Comment: Here is my first lesson code. pstlesson1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}(4,5) 
\psgrid
\psframe(0.7,2)(3.3,3) 
\rput(2,2.5){First Example}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: I tried the above code to try to plot tangent code. It does not work. I see line 13 that package xkeyval/pstlesson1.tex:13: Package xkeyval Error: `yMinValue' undefined in families `
,pstricks,pst-plot,pst-node,pst-3d,pstricks-add'.

Comment: The axis labels like '-3pi/2' appear horizontally and vertically like 6. However, no axes. No tangent curves. I need help to compile this .Thanks

Comment: @mark: if `yMinValue` is unknown then you have to update your files, see http://texnik.dante.de/

Comment: I am downloading the package TDS. The next step is how to install this set of macros.

Answer (score 2):

see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#TS
for configuring TeXShop for using `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Alternetively use

```
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
```

and run your document with `pdflatex -shell-escape`. The above page show how `shell-escape` can be enabled.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the linked image shows the German localisation of TeXShop, it's not terribly helpful: the issue is not setting up TeXShop to use `latex->divps->ps2pdf` (which it is set up to do out of the box) but how to tell TeXShop to do that for a particular document.  See [How to run PSTricks in TeXShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66051/2693).

Comment: Does that mean I removed the 'file-line error' statements in the window: Latex(default:pdflatex).

Answer (score 0):

Another method, compile it with `pdflatex --shell-escape filename`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dummy.tex}
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6.5,-4)(6.5,7.5)
    \psaxes[trigLabelBase=2,dx=\psPiH,xunit=\psPi,trigLabels]%
        {->}(0,0)(-1.7,-3.5)(1.77,6.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{algebraic=true}
    \psplot[yMaxValue=6,yMinValue=-3,linewidth=1.6pt,plotpoints=2000,
        linecolor=red]{-4.55}{4.55}{tan(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\GetImage#1{%
    \immediate\write18{latex dummy}%
    \immediate\write18{dvips dummy}%
    \immediate\write18{ps2pdf dummy.ps}%
    \includegraphics[scale=#1]{dummy}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\fbox{\GetImage{1}}

\end{document}
```